# How to buy the right comptabile SDD drive to my lenovou labtop

Tags: laptop, hard-disk, ssd

I want to replace a HDD (Seagate [ST1000LM035-1RK172](https://www.seagate.com/www-content/datasheets/pdfs/mobile-hddDS1861-2-1603-en_US.pdf)) in a [Lenovo Flex 5-1570 (Type 81CA)](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/flex_5-1470_5-1570_hmm_201703.pdf) with an SSD.  I am looking for 500 GB or 1 TB. Is this SSD [SAMSUNG 1TB 860 EVO-Series 2.5](https://www.walmart.com/ip/SAMSUNG-1TB-860-EVO-Series-2-5-SATA-III-Internal-SSD-Single-Unit-Version-MZ-76E1T0B-AM/201411818?fbclid=IwAR3_JvxvmBvj8Sn_ktVN0Nu89KPpEFhcrGcGaJw4HW7Ln4ErG7s9TzuqCss) compatible for my Lenovo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your laptop can hold a 2.5" SATA SSD like the Samsung 860 Evo. So a clear yes to your question.
It can also be expanded with an m.2 NVMe SSD, in case you want to keep your hard drive for more total storage.

Comment: Note: the HDD might be 9mm thick, where most SSDs are 7mm, so padding might be required. It's readily and cheaply available as something you stick on the SSD

Comment: As per its spec sheet, the ST1000LM035-1RK172) is 7mm.